# How to open particular post on the click on push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift2, ios9

in my app i implemented push notification. when my app is in running state and if push notification come i am handle that with this code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
              print(userInfo)

    myid = (userInfo["id"] as? String)!
    print(myid)
    if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary,
        let alert = notification["alert"] as? String {
            var alertCtrl = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: alert as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertCtrl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            // Find the presented VC...
            var presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController
            while (presentedVC!.presentedViewController != nil)  {
                presentedVC = presentedVC!.presentedViewController
            }
            presentedVC!.presentViewController(alertCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

What i want :: when my app is not running and if push notification come i want to open perticular post based on that notification post id. so how can i do this?
Here is my code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(SVProgressHUDMaskType.Black)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    let dicTemp = launchOptions?["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]
    if dicTemp != nil{


        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


       myid = (dicTemp["id"] as? String)!


        let controller:pushnotificationpostViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pushnotificationpostViewController") as! pushnotificationpostViewController
        navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        window?.rootViewController = navigation
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }

    else
    {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller:MainViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController
        navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        window?.rootViewController = navigation
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }


    //print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("pushnotify")as! Bool)

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)


   if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("pushnotify")) != nil
   {
        pushnotification = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("pushnotify") as! Bool
       // let notificationcheck = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("pushnotify") as! Bool

        if (pushnotification == true)
        {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else
        {
            application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
        }

   }
  else
   {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }


    return true
}
```

but by this code i am not getting id means myid is getting nil. so how can i do this?

Comment: does your code work when app is running?

Comment: yes its working when app is running@SuhasPatil

Answer (score 1):

> i think when you quit your application the
>   didReceiveRemoteNotification method not gets called when you tap on
>   the notification, instead the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
>   gets called there you have to check weather application is launched by
>   notification

Put below code in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
var notification: UILocalNotification = (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification)
if notification != nil {
// handle your notification
}
```

above code is for handling the push notifications if your using local notification then try:

```
// if launched by the local notification
var notification: UILocalNotification = (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification)
if notification != nil {

}
```

Comment: ok man not used your code but your answer give me a clue and solved my problem. Thanx buddy@Suhas patil