# Can't present ViewController correctly on notification tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using `Objective-C`. I want to present an `infoViewController` with content from a notification.

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [self presentViewControllerWithUserInfo:userInfo];
}


- (void)presentViewControllerWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    infoViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];
    vc.infoString = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"info"] objectForKey:@"string"];

    //NSLog(@"class: %@", [self.window.rootViewController class]);

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I present the `infoViewController` by the `rootViewController`. But what if the App enters background when it's not in the `rootViewController`? The construct looks like this: [image]

The App enters into background when it's in the "Another Page", and I sent a `Notification` to my App. When I try to open my App from the notification. The console told me this:[image]

And fail to present `infoViewController`. Someone plz help me.

Comment: You can refere my answer here at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709454/how-to-open-particular-post-on-the-click-on-push-notification/36709695#36709695 if app is killed then what happen with push notification event is explained here.

Answer (score 1):

Error log is telling you that you're trynig to present InfoViewController from a controller that is not in foreground, and it's right because the other controller has been presented.

My solution for this:

1. Create a **BaseViewController** class (if you don't have yet) that should be extended from all controllers of your application.
2. Create a **static** UIViewController property in BaseViewController called CURRENT_CONTROLLER.
3. Set **CURRENT_CONTROLLER = self** in viewDidAppear() method.
4. Remember to call always super.viewDidAppear() if you override this method in any view controller.

Then, when you receive remote notification do something like this:

```
infoViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];
vc.infoString = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"info"] objectForKey:@"string"];

if (BaseViewController.CURRENT_CONTROLLER != nil) {
    [BaseViewController.CURRENT_CONTROLLER presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    // app just started, your code works well
    // this code could never be executed if you extend BaseViewController from all your view controllers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i think when you quit your application the
>   didReceiveRemoteNotification method not gets called when you tap on
>   the notification, instead the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
>   gets called there you have to check weather application is launched by
>   notification

Put below code in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
 NSDictionary *launchOptionDict = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (launchOptionDict) {
       [self presentViewControllerWithUserInfo:launchOptionDict];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call method with some delay. try this.

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
//code to be executed on the main queue after delay
[self presentViewControllerWithUserInfo:userInfo];
});
```